# Bash script, ask for user input, to change a directory, sub directorys, and file's mtime atime linux recursively

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, date, touch

Using
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

I am a bash scripting novice, not sure where to begin except at shebang `#!`. 
The following command.

- `touch -a -m -t 201501010000.00 somefile.txt`, will modify "somefile.txt" access time and modification time.
- Is there a way to have a bash script?

  1. Operating within the directory "/mnt/harddrive/BASE/"
  2. Prompt user input for. "somefilename.txt", or "somedirectoryname".
  3. Prompt user input for. "datetime sequence". Instead of using the current time-stamp, explicitly specify the time/date using `-t` and `-d` options.
  4. Recursively change/modify. "atime", "mtime" on "sub-directory’s" within the BASE directory and "files" within that "sub-directory".
     AND
  5. Change/modify. "atime", "mtime" of "somefilename.txt" located in the "/mnt/hardrive/BASE/" directory.

  Optional 6. Append "mtime" to "somefilename" and "somedirectoryname" before the file extension. ie: "somefilename-01-01-2015.txt" or "somedirectoryname-01-01-2015". Prompt user: do you want to append "mtime" to "somefilename.txt" "YES/NO" if "YES/NO" continue.

  7. `stat` the directory and file output to the console or "/tmp" directory text file and display with `cat` then delete the "sometmpfile" `rm -r`.

Comment: Welcome to U & L SE. Try splitting every point of your question into a separate question and try asking it for better responses. Also, check the already existing questions and if you still feel if your question is not answered, post a new question by adding a link to the questions that you referred to.

Comment: 4. and 5. apply either to the directory or the file given in 2., so actually they are like 4a), 4b), correct?

Comment: "Is there a way to have a bash script?" - yes there is. You might want to hit up a `bash` scripting primer to get the basics under your belt.

Comment: @nlu yes, rootdirectory/file. directory/file, /sub-directory/file. Does that clarify anything?

Comment: @datUser, I knew this could be accomplished with bash, I have read the bash scripting primer, as i said I am a novice, thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# 1. change directory
cd "/mnt/harddrive/BASE/" 

# 2. prompt for name of file or directory
echo -n "file or directory name: "
# ...  and read it
read HANDLE

# 2. b - check if it exists and is readable
if [ ! -r "$HANDLE" ] 
then
    echo "$HANDLE is not readable";
    # if not, exit with an exit code != 0
    exit 2;
fi

# 3. prompt for datetime
echo -n "datetime of file/directory: "
# ... and read it
read TIMESTAMP

# 4. set datetime for HANDLE (file or directory + files) 
find $HANDLE | xargs touch -a -m -t "$TIMESTAMP"

# 5. ask, if the name should be changed
echo -n "change name of file by appending mtime to the name (y/n)?: "
# ... and read it
read YES_NO
if [ "$YES_NO" == "y" ]
then
    # get yyyy-mm-dd of modification time 
    SUFFIX_TS=$(stat -c "%y" $HANDLE  | cut -f 1 -d" ")
    # rename, supposed, the suffix is always .txt
    mv $HANDLE $(basename $HANDLE txt)-$SUFFIX_TS.txt
    # let HANDLE hold the name for further processing
    HANDLE=$HANDLE-$TIMESTAMP.$SUFFIX
fi

# 7. stat to console
stat $HANDLE
```

This is just partly tested, but should be a start.

To get a an understanding of what is happening here, you should look up the following commands:
echo, read, test, cut, touch, find, xargs

Besides you should understand several basic bash concepts, i.e. parameter substitution, command substitution and pipes.

Comment: Thank you, it's a great start, I will check your suggestions and begin with using your first example answer, I will reply with the outcome and further additions. Thank you again!